# Unable to configure oracle 11g net server

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I was install oracle 11g in my windows server 2008 workstation. After I try to configure oracle net server with port number 1521 . But ONS error say to me as a "use other port this port is already user". PLs tell me how i solve this problem
This is a screen shot.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_sjxK048-u8dkpoZnd3V3RQUjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First, this is an impossible question to answer. Second, it is on the wrong site.

Comment: why you say as a wrong site...?

Comment: This site is about programming issues, not your database config problems.

Comment: Ok thanx . I will post it in database site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some other service is listening on port 1521. 
open an terminal and type

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

it prints a list with tcp port and pid,

lookup the pid in the taskmanager,

then you can reconfigure the service or remove the service.

you may also consider to use a different port for your oracle database (simplest solution)

Comment: Thanx you. I check it in resource monitor and 1521 use TNSLSNR.EXE